# bzr not being able to use the right python version in msys2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, bazaar, msys2

I am using Msys2 from PortableApps under Win10.

I cannot run `bzr`. I am adding below the output of a few command that illustrate the issue, and provide information that can guide the answer:

```
$ bzr
  File "/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 177
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
$ type bzr
bzr is hashed (/usr/bin/bzr)
$ python2 /usr/bin/bzr
  File "/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 177
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
$ python2 -m trace --count /usr/bin/bzr
  File "/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 177
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:...
$ type python
python is hashed (/usr/bin/python)
$ type python2
python2 is hashed (/usr/bin/python2)
$ head -1 /usr/bin/bzr
#!/usr/bin/python2
$ python --version
Python 3.7.4
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/c/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7:/c/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

My main question is:

**How can I execute `bzr` commands, without radically changing my configuration / removing python3?**

In addition, I wonder why the `trace` did not show more info than it did.

Comment: What does ``python --version`` output? Do you perhaps have PYTHONPATH set to the Python3 path?

Comment: @jelmer - Please see updated OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be happening because your PYTHONPATH is pointing at a Python3-specific path, and it contains python files that Python 2 can not parse.

Unsetting PYTHONPATH, either permanently or just for bzr, should resolve the issue:

```
$ PYTHONPATH= bzr rocks
```

Comment: What worked:
`export $PYTHONPATH /c/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python2.7:/c/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.
I will have to check how to handle this more permanent and robustly, specifically for `bzr` without interfering with my regular use of msys2.